# Incorrect data retrieved from SQL data base - Repetitive data being pulled - PHP

Tags: php, sql

Hello :) I have a PHP/SQL database that is an online ordering system. Orders are displayed via an HTML table each with a view button to view the order details. I have written the following code to retrieve data from the SQL data base and display it in HTML.

Currently the echo statements are retrieving the same data (from line 1) on my SQL database and not returning unique results depending on the orderID that is clicked.

The `<legend>` does display the correct ID (Order details #$id) however the other data (echo) keeps repeating the data from order 1 within my SQL.

Is there potentially something wrong with my $query or is there something else wrong? I am a beginner developer keep in mind so the code is most likely not perfect.

```
<?php
include "checksession.php";
checkUser();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Waipukurau Pizzeria - View an order</title>

</head>
<body>

<?php
include "config.php"; //load in any variables
$DBC = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", DBUSER, DBPASSWORD, DBDATABASE);

//check if the connection was good
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL. ".mysqli_connect_error() ;
    exit; //stop processing the page further
}

//do some simple validation to check if id exists
$id = $_GET['id'];
if (empty($id) or !is_numeric($id)) {
 echo "<h2>No order found!</h2>"; //simple error feedback
 exit;
} 
//prepare query to send to server

$query = 'SELECT orders.orderID, orderon, pizzaextras, firstname, lastname, qty, pizza FROM orders
INNER JOIN customer ON orders.customerID = customer.customerID
INNER JOIN orderlines ON orders.orderID = orderlines.orderID
INNER JOIN fooditems ON orderlines.itemID = fooditems.itemID';
$result = mysqli_query($DBC, $query);
$rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
?>
    
<h1>Pizza Order Details View</h1>
<h2><a href="listorders.php">[Return to the orders listing]</a><a href="index.php">[Return to the main page]</a></h2>

<?php
//make sure there are orders
if ($rowcount > 0) {
    echo "<fieldset><legend>Order details #$id</legend><dl>";
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo "<dt>Date & time ordered for</dt><dd>".$row['orderon']."</dd>".PHP_EOL;
    echo "<dt>Customer name:</dt><dd>".$row['lastname'].", ".$row['firstname']."</dd>".PHP_EOL;
    echo "<dt>Extras:</dt><dd>".$row['pizzaextras']."</dd>".PHP_EOL;
    echo "<dt>Pizzas:</dt><dd>".$row['pizza']." X ".$row['qty']."</dd>".PHP_EOL;
    echo "</dl></fieldset>".PHP_EOL;
} else echo "<h2>No order found!</h2>"; //Feedback

mysqli_free_result($result); //free memory from the query
mysqli_close($DBC); //close connection
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to use the Order ID in a WHERE clause in your sql query

Comment: Thank you! Had played around with the where statement (obviously had it wrong) but now it's working.

Answer (score -1):

Hey I think you are accessing the data incorrectly, after the check

`IF ($rowcount > 0) {`

Make another loop straight after with, ending where the above clause ends:

`WHILE ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {`